# Integrating Spark jobs with Apache Ranger Plugin for Authorization with Hive tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-ranger

We are running spark jobs in the Kubernetes cluster and we want to enable authorization for spark jobs with Ranger policies defined on hive tables, I could see that there are no direct plugins available to connect with Ranger from the spark. Can someone please help how i can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

Yes there are no direct plugins that are available, but ranger lets you define your own plugins as well. You can check this plugin - [spark-ranger](https://github.com/yaooqinn/spark-ranger). This is primarily enabled as a spark extension.

Comment: Still supported?

Comment: Yes it's now part of apache-submarine security. Although the codebase is very straightforward and can be extended to meet the requirements of any project.

Comment: Thx nice to know